# peaks and bringing them down to be more in line with the overall average of the signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

I have a signal 
In which sharp peaks are produced.  Is there a way for me to bring the amplitude of these peaks down to be more in line with the overall average of the signal? 
[Link to example data in text file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/example_data_with_peak.txt)

**Image of data**
[image]

I'm using Octave 3.2.4/Matlab

Thanks

Comment: Could you just use max/min operations to clamp these spikes to an acceptable range?

Comment: @Paul R Yes but how do I get the range in-between the two green lines to bring it down to?

Comment: You could use e.g. mean +/- 3 SD. Or another approach might be median filtering.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want some method of robustly estimate your mean.
One way I can think of is defining a percentage of outliers (say 5%), then you sort your entries and discard the top 5%. Take the average of what's left - and that's it!

```
s = sort( abs(signal) );
TopPer = 0.05; % remove top 5% as outliers
n = floor( numel(signal) * ( 1 - TopPer ) );
robustMean = mean( s(1:n) );
% clamped signal
clampedSignal = min( max( signal, -robustMean ), robustMean );
```

Comment: This is an audio signal so I cant sort the values.